# How to install Ubuntu 18.04.* in a single partition on a dual boot with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Ubuntu 18.04.4
Windows 10 Home

I decided to clean up the HD, and reinstall Windows and Ubuntu as dual boot, this time giving the bare minimum to Win and the rest to Ubu. I've installed Win and here is the disc so far:
[image]

Before I began again, Ubuntu was formerly in sda5. I booted Live USB 18.04.4 and got to here:
[image]

I chose the easy option and was confronted with the choice to mutually resize sda5 (Files) and a new partition sda6 for Ubuntu:
[image]
What on earth is Files for? Why can't everything just be thrown into sda5 without an sda6? How big should I make Files? I want swap, /home, and root / to all be in one partition. Isn't there now a swap file? And I don't want a separate partition for /home because if I set its size wrongly it will have to be resized in a trade-off with / some time in the future.

I backed up and tried **Something Else**, which introduced me to a world of terror:
[image]
Selecting /dev/sda and clicking New Partition Table invited me to wipe my HD clean and install new partitions, not what was wanted at all. Selecting /dev/sda5 did not give me any new options to try.

My previous adventures in making a dual boot were uneventful. But this Files/Ubuntu partitioning has stumped me. Answers very welcome!

Comment: I don't think you should go with the "easy option".
You have to do manually. Moreover you also have to create a swap partition (usually as big as installed RAM).
Finally, as just a suggestion, consider to create a "shared" partition to use with both unix and windows. 
I also recently installed Mint with Win, and have the following partion: 8GB Ram, 30 GB Unix, 60 Windows, and all the remaing space for data accessible from both os.

Comment: If you want more control, use Something Else. Only required partition is / (root) usually ext4. Ubuntu now uses swap file, so swap partition not required. But often better to have smaller (25 to 30GB) / (root) and larger /home and/or data partition(s).

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I went with Something Else, discovered the Change button to make /dev/sda5 / (root) and away I went. Put it all in that partition with no /home partition. The data and apps can sort out their space requirements between them. Will modify my question to show what I did. The ext2fsd Win app and mounting the Win partition in Ubuntu will allow me to access files wherever they may be.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should go with 'Something else' option in Installation Type Menu(Your 2nd image) and then resize partitions according to your convenience.